# Probability models in SAS

Tags: probability, sas

What sort of tests are available in SAS that allow you to figure out what the probability of an event occurring is? And I do mean probability, not odds.

Specifically, I would like to know what is the probability a person might say yes vs. no to a particular type of surgery based on their age, insurance status, or other a combination of other factors?

I have tried logistic regression, but it appears to only return odds, and again, I am interested in a statistical test that returns probabilities, not odds.

You would think I could just google, "probability models (or tests) SAS" and get an answer, but strangely enough, I haven't - at least not one that is clear. So here I am.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For answers about SAS you need to go elsewhere.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sas+user's+guide

Answer (score 1):

Logistic regression does of course provide predicted probabilities. You simply obtain them by back-transforming the corresponding linear predictor (on the logit scale). Most software packages will even do this transformation and the creation of confidence intervals for you (including SAS, if you read the documentation - see e.g. the PREDICTED option in the OUTPUT statement of PROC LOGISTIC).

Without knowing more on your specific problem it is hard to say what kind of test you are looking for, but the typical hypotheses about probabilities that I see commonly used can also simply be formulated in terms of odds.